# Can I force a constructor to put a stricter bound on its generic type?

Tags: java, generics, constructor, type-bounds

In java, generic classes have constructors to construct instances of some generic type. This is simple, and callers of the constructor can specify any type that is within bounds.

Is it possible to have a constructor that puts stricter bounds on that generic type?
E.g., have a constructor that forces the generic type to be `String`.

```java
public class GenericClass<T extends Serializable> {
    public GenericClass() {
        // normal constructor
    }

    public GenericClass(String argument) {
        // Can I force this constructor to construct a `GenericClass<String>`?
    }
}

// The first constructor can have any type
GenericClass<String> stringInstance = new GenericClass<>();
GenericClass<Integer> intInstance = new GenericClass<>();

// The second constructor is limited to `GenericClass<String>`
stringInstance = new GenericClass<>("with generic type String is okay");
intInstance = new GenericClass<>("with other generic type is not okay");
```

I would like to have the last line fail because of incompatible types.

Is this possible?

Comment: It seems you're overcomplicating. If you want to force `String`, just don't use generics.

Comment: I want to have the generic type in most cases. It's just that String is the default. In my actual case (not the example I put here) the constructor that yields the String variant is actually a lot simpler than the normal case. Because I assume it to be String now while in theory it could be anything, I get warnings about "unchecked" casts though.

Comment: You can do this if you abandon using constructors.  Use factory methods instead which delegate to private constructors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to cause the last line to fail is this:

```
public class GenericClass<T extends Serializable> {
    public GenericClass() {
        // normal constructor
    }

    public GenericClass(T argument) {

    }
}
```

But obviously that doesn't stop people from calling `new GenericClass<>(1)`.

Alternatively, you can write a factory method `ofString`:

```
public static GenericClass<String> ofString(String s) {
    GenericClass<String> gc = new GenericClass<>();
    // do stuff to gc
    return gc;
}
```

Comment: Subclasses of the GenericClass should all implement such factory method then, and duplicate the behaviour of the parent factory method instead of just calling it?

Comment: @neXus you are right. If you have subclasses then this method will create a lot of boilerplate code.

Comment: I can make the constructor `protected` and expect the subclasses to honour the fact that it should only be used to construct instances for which `<T>` is of type `String`. Each subclass then needs a simple factory method that just delegates to the constructor.

Answer (score 4):

```
public GenericClass(String argument)
```

The problem with this is how is the compiler supposed to know that `String` is `T`? There is no link between the parameter and the generic type parameter and no way to specify one. You could use

```
public GenericClass(T argument)
```

and construct it with

```
new GenericClass<>("foo");
```

but that would allow `GenericClass` to be instantiated with an object of any type.

You can achieve roughly what you want using inheritance, though you need to introduce a second class:

```
class GenericClass<T extends Serializable> {
    public GenericClass() {

    }
}

class StringClass extends GenericClass<String> {
    public StringClass(String argument) {

    }
}
```

You can introduce an interface and have both classes implement that if you want to avoid using inheritance. That's what I'd do.